# Cloud Function annotateImage() returns 'Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1' to native iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-vision

I am creating an ImageAnnotator for a native iOS mobile app using Firebase Cloud Functions, following the Firebase documentation for the [iOS client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/ios/recognize-text#swift_2) and [Cloud Function](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/vision-annotate-images/functions/src/index.ts). Yet upon calling 'annotateImage' client-side the error 'Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1' is returned. I am using XCode 13.

My client code:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import Resolver

class ImageAnnotator: ObservableObject {
  @LazyInjected var functions: Functions
  @Published var annotatedText: String?
  @Published var error: NSError?

  func annotateImage(imageData: Data) {
    let base64encodedImage = imageData.base64EncodedString()

    let requestData = [
      "image": ["content": base64encodedImage],
      "features": ["type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"],
      "imageContext": ["languageHints": ["en"]]
    ]

    functions.httpsCallable("annotateImage").call(requestData) { (result, error) in
      if let error = error as NSError? {
        self.error = error
        return
      }
      
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let annotation = (result?.data as? [String: Any])?["fullTextAnnotation"] as? [String: Any]
        else {
          return
        }
        print("%nComplete annotation:")
        let text = annotation["text"] as? String ?? ""
        print("%n\(text)")
        self.annotatedText = text
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My index.js cloud function code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
exports.annotateImage = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "unauthenticated",
      "annotateImage must be called while authenticated."
    );
  }
  try {
    return await client.annotateImage(JSON.parse(data));
  } catch (e) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", e.message, e.details);
  }
});
```

What could be causing this error to return from the annotateImage() call?

Comment: The first parameter of the JSON.parse should be string

Comment: Error in OP is resolved. The JSON response data in result returns successfully after I experimented more with Codable. However, now it seems the program is unable to conditionally downcast result.data to [String: Any] in the following line of code: 

`guard let annotation = (result?.data as? [String: Any])?["fullTextAnnotation"] as? [String: Any] else { return }`

Any ideas?

Comment: Since you resolved the error, you can post the answer and accept it so it is visible to the community. Also I suggest to create a new post with regards to your new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve the error by using the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66609620/firebase-ios-annotateimage-function-returning-unexpected-token-o-in-json-at-pos?noredirect=1&lq=1):

1. Change the 'features' dictionary value of requestData to an array.
2. Pass requestData as encoded string JSON to annotateImage().

But still the line

```
guard let annotation = (result?.data as? [String: Any])?["fullTextAnnotation"] as? [String: Any]
```

was returning nil.

The line was not correctly parsing the result object. I solved the nil return by serially downcasting result.data to an NSArray, and then index 0 of the NSArray to an NSDictionary. Then I was able to access the fullAnnotatedText field of the NSDictionary as a [String: Any].

Full code:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import Resolver

class ImageAnnotator: ObservableObject {
  @LazyInjected var functions: Functions
  @Published var annotatedText: String?
  
  func annotateImage(imageData: Data) {

    struct requestData: Encodable {
      let image: [String: Data]
      let features = [["type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"]]

      init(imageData: Data) {
        image = ["content": imageData]
      }
    }

    let encoder = JSONEncoder()

    let encodedData = try! encoder.encode(requestData(imageData: imageData))
    let string = String(data: encodedData, encoding: .utf8)!

    functions.httpsCallable("annotateImage").call(string) { (result, error) in
      if let error = error as NSError? {
        if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
          let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
          let message = error.localizedDescription
          let details = error.userInfo[FunctionsErrorDetailsKey]
          print("ERROR \(String(describing: message)), CODE \(String(describing: code)), DETAILS \(String(describing: details))")
        }
        return
      }
      
      print("Success.")
      
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        /* Parse result object */
        guard let nsarray = result?.data as? NSArray
        else {
          return
        }
        
        guard let nsdictionary = nsarray[0] as? NSDictionary
        else {
          return
        }

        guard let fullTextAnnotation = nsdictionary["fullTextAnnotation"] as? [String: Any]
        else {
          return
        }
        
        let text = fullTextAnnotation["text"] as? String ?? ""
        print("Recognized text: \(text)")
      }
    }
  }
}
```